# MP3 IDv3 Tagger

Tags: audio, mp3, music, tags

I am trying to find a program (for windows) that will automatically scan all my music files, and replace all of the IDv3 tags with the correct values, and album art (if possible). Most of my tags are incorrect, or have weird variables in them too like the year, or incorrect album information.

Has anyone found a program that can do this? I've used, and tried the following programs in the past and nothing has worked, or sets albums as compilations, rather than the actual album they came from.

- MusicBee
- MP3 Tagger
- Mass Tagger
- Tag & Rename
- Magic MP3 Tagger
- Robot Butler
- MusicBrainz Picard
- TagScanner
- Sound Maven
- MP Tagger
- MP3 Tag

Among a few other, open source ones I can't recall right now. I have racking my brain for the last few weeks to find a program to do this for me, with over 80,000 songs I do not have time time, or energy to go through and do this.

Some of these programs will get the artist and title correct, but are way off on other things like year, lyrics, composer, etc.

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Additionally, product requests are considered [off-topic or SU](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a dup if i've tried the program they marked as the answer and it didn't work for me.

Comment: i would not call this a product request, i'm merely asking if other users have had better luck with what I've had no luck with.

Comment: Just because the answer(s) aren't what you need, doesn't make it a different question.  Besides, you are not going to find a program that's 100% accurate for 100% of files, as the DBs out there are not 100% accurate, plus there's compilations, release dates for re-releases, etc.,  etc.  Getting perfect metadata is going to take some time and effort.  Waiting until you had 80K files to do was a mistake. ;)

Comment: I don't understand how this is not a different question, for every 100 users that the answer you say this is a dup to may solve, there are 10 or 20 who does not. i will no longer be using this website, anytime i post something specialized it's always compared to a generic answer that does not resolve my issue.

Comment: @ Brad J Trammell You say it hasn't worked for you. I think you should clarify your exact requirement in terms of *how* the program *should* work. Especially because my experience with at least 2 programs you mention has been extremely good. They fetch the data from cddb/other, so getting the data wrong is extremely unlikely.

Comment: "Some of these programs will get the artist and title correct, but are way off on other things like year, lyrics, composer, etc."

I stated above why they're not working for me. I've never had a good experience with any of these, like I said, rather than getting actual album names, they'll use Compilations, even when the songs are pulled directly off the artists album.

Comment: I would like to see the program get the correct information, i honestly don't even care if album art information is not an option, i just want the CORRECT album information, without having to worry that the program is going to add compilations, to songs that were pulled from an artists album.

Comment: @BradJTrammell I had the same struggle and I know most of these programs. Surprisingly the best identifying algorithm I found, was an android app ([Sound Search for Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.ears)). Maybe there are PC alternatives which work the same way

Comment: None of these solutions were able to resolve my issues, i just physically went through each file and rewrote the data myself, including the album art. I was not able to find a suitable program to do it for me. I tested one file through each of the ones I had listed before again today, and almost all of the programs (even with some of the ID3 information already in the file) completely rewrote the tag with incorrect album, artist and title information. I will keep watching this thread in hopes that maybe someone will be able to come up with a windows based solution...here's to hoping.